# In Debian-derived flavours, what does the 'network' line in /etc/network/interfaces actually do?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I'm trying to understand the syntax of `ifupdown` a bit better, and on [several](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html) [sites](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/) detailing fairly straightforward static configurations, the example documentation includes a line stating `network 192.168.0.0' -- or something obviously similar. [For example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces),

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.33
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    network 192.168.10.0
    gateway 192.168.10.254 
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.254
```

What *exactly* does this line do? I can't imagine that it contains anything that the netmask + address doesn't convey about, for example, broadcast addresses. There is much useful documentation about the myriad array of powerful things that one can do with `/etc/network/interfaces` available online. Almost all of it details various aspects of networking. Therefore, googling isn't terribly helpful!

Comment: It's optional if you got already broadcast an address as explained by Julie. I haven't tested it but possibly it could let you use that line instead of the broadcast one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `network` doesn't have to be specified as it is simply the result of `address & netmask` (`&` is a binary and):

```
192.168.10.33 & 255.255.255.0 = 192.168.10.0
```

It may make it easier to understand by showing it in binary:

```
  11000000.10101000.00001010.00100001 (192.168.10.33)
& 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 (255.255.255.0)
-------------------------------------
  11000000.10101000.00001010.00000000 (192.168.10.0)
```

Comment: So it _is_ just the network prefix. Why does ifconfig allow one to specify it separately, given the facts that essentially everyone has to use subnets, the  binary and is many-to-one, and therefore I can't easily foresee a situation under which you might want to specify `network` explicitly?

Comment: Many of those values are inter-changeable since they are calculations on one another and can easily be computed if not specified.

Comment: A common static IP configuration only needs the IP address, gateway and network mask which in its simples form can be represented as `address 192.168.10.33/24` for the IP address, along with its gateway.